# Java Frame Layout

Tags: java, swing, authentication, interface

I have to make a login interface.I tried to use the border layout instead of using this model for the frame, but when I go to write setLocationRelativeTo (null), the internal components of the frame are displayed wrong. Some tips for how to set the frame at the center of the screen and the internal components at the center of the screen and displayed well and in specific coordinates?

```
class Login extends JFrame {
        JLabel label1;
        final JTextField text1;
        public Login(){
        setTitle("title");
        setLayout(null); //output on left-corner of screen or
       setLocationRelativeTo(null); // output on the middle with components displayed wrong
        label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setText("text");
        text1 = new JTextField(15);
        label1.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 20);
        text1.setBounds(200, 100, 200, 20);
        add(label1);
        add(text1);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500, 400);
```

`}public static void main(string [] args){` 
`
  . . . . . .

`new Login();}`

Comment: For a simple layout question, you should a) show us your attempt to use the tool you're trying to use (here layout managers) b) show us a [minimal compilable runnable program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem. c) show a picture of your desired layout and your actual layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem can be solved by calling setLocationRelativeTo(null); *after* calling `setSize(...)`

```
  setSize(500, 400);
  setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

But having said that, my actual recommendations are:

- **Don't** call `setSize(...)`. Let the layout managers do this for you.
- Do use layout managers.
- Do call `pack()` before `setVisible(true)`
- Do call `setLocationRelativeTo(null);` after pack and before setVisible if you want to center the GUI.
- Do learn to create a [minimal, compilable, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking similar questions. Your current code does not follow the rules of this simple tool, forcing us to do this for you.

Comment: My code is about 450 rows of logic and only 30 of graphic to show you a correct example i had to cut parts that do not serve

Comment: @CiMat: please read the link before making these statements. Do that and you'll see that your statement above doesn't make sense. We're not asking for the whole program, but your posted code uses fields that you've not declared anywhere, it has no imports, no main method. Again, at least read the links we provide.

Comment: yes,thank you. I' m not a very good graphic i like to do a logic programs, but i' ve to use the layout manager,that you suggested